# Can someone explain why my luhn's algo fails?

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cs50.h>

short unsigned int numlen(unsigned long long n);
bool isValidCC(unsigned long long int n);
unsigned short int first_n_nums(unsigned short int n, unsigned short int x);


int main(void) 
{
    unsigned long long num = 0;
    num = get_long("Enter your card number ");
    
    if(numlen(num) == 15 && (first_n_nums(num, 2) == 34 || first_n_nums(num, 2) == 37) && isValidCC(num) == true)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if((numlen(num) == 13 || numlen(num) == 16)  && first_n_nums(num, 1) == 4 && isValidCC(num) == true)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if(numlen(num) == 16 && (first_n_nums(num, 2) == 51 || first_n_nums(num, 2) == 52 || first_n_nums(num, 2) == 53 || first_n_nums(num, 2) == 54 || first_n_nums(num, 2) == 55)  && isValidCC(num) == true)
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    
}

unsigned short int first_n_nums(unsigned short int n, unsigned short int x)
{
    while(n > pow(10,x))
    {
        n /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}    
    
   

short unsigned int numlen(unsigned long long n)
{
    short unsigned int count = 0;
    while (n !=0)
    {
        n /= 10;  //removes last digit
        count++; //counts the num of digits removed
    }
    return count;
}

bool isValidCC(unsigned long long int n)
{

    // take user input and add elements to array in reverse
     int arr1[(numlen(n))]; // declares but can't Initialize an array of n ;
     
     for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int) ; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i <(int) (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int)) ; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = n % 10; //Appends last digit to an array
        n /= 10; // removes that last digit
    }
    
    
    // since arr1 = x digits long, arr2 is every second digit so its x/2 long 
     int arr2[((sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int))*2)];
    
    //initializing garbage data to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int) ; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = 0;
    }
    
    // multiplies, seperates, and sums arr2 elements
    int sum_of_arr2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1,  a = 0,  b = 0 ; i < (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int)) ; i += 2) // sizeof(array) = n of elements * sizeof(type of n)
    {
        a = arr1[i] * 2;
        if( a > 9)
        {
            b = a % 10;
            a /= 10;
            arr2[i] = b;
            sum_of_arr2 += b;
        }
        arr2[i-1] = a; // cz i currenrly is one idex ahead
        sum_of_arr2 += a;
    }
    
    // adds other elements of arr1 to sum_of_arr2
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (sizeof(arr1)/4) ; i += 2) // sizeof(array) = n of elements * sizeof(type of n)
    {
        sum_of_arr2 += arr1[i];
    }
    
    // returns true or false
    if (sum_of_arr2 % 10 != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can someone pls explain why this fails for values like:

371449635398431 - expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"

5555555555554444 - expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "INVALID\n"

5105105105105100-  expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "VISA\n"

4111111111111111 - expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"

4222222222222 - expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"

Comment: We need to see what `first_n_nums`, `isValidCC`, and `numlen` to help.  This code as-is will not compile so we cannot even make a good guess.  I'd open a debugger and see what is being returned per function to make each function is doing what you expect...

Comment: Rather than incur FP inaccuracies, move `while(n > pow(10,x))` to an integer based solution.

Comment: You should not be using floating point for any of this.  In fact, you probably shouldn't be using integers.  Strings would provide a more general representation that's not subject to length limitations.

Comment: You could just `return (sum_of_arr2 % 10 == 0);` Likewise your zeroing of the array is useless, because you're going to fill in every digit anyway...

Comment: To follow up, what happens if the CC number is "0003734"?  An integer based routine will return "3734" and could easily fall into the AMEX category if I added more digits.  String based numbers solve that issue and more...

Comment: You take a lot of time to setup `arr2`, but never use it after adding all the digits into it.  Is that a mistake?  BTW, `arr2` is 4x bigger than needed due to you using a *2 instead of a /2 on its creation.

Comment: Today is a good day to learn to use a debugger. Every day is a good time to learn to use a debugger. It is also a good day to learn the concept of unit tests. Does your `first_n_nums` do what you want it to do?

Comment: As mentioned by Tom, card (and phone) numbers are not integers, but a *string of digits*, and they are best stored and handled that way. One good reason is that you can't know how many leading zeros there are; and it's perverse to accept a string input, convert it to an integer, and then back to the digits which had already been given. Sometimes (often) in coding, you have to drop what you did and take another approach.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.Yes that helped, Every function was correct. But if-else was not working updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your function

```
    unsigned short int first_n_nums(unsigned short int n, unsigned short int x)
```

You are passing `unsigned short int` instead of `unsigned long long`, so you can just get the max value of `unsigned short int` instead of the real value.

The output:

```
    371449635398431 - "AMEX\n"

    5555555555554444 - "MASTERCARD\n"

    5105105105105100- "MASTERCARD\n"

    4111111111111111 - "INVALID\n" - Note that the output you said you were expecting is incorrect because the input length is 14 instead of 13.

    4222222222222 - "VISA\n"
```